# sharepoint 2013 List View Webpart Filter Dropdown

Tags: html, css, sharepoint

I have a list view webpart where the title font is White and the background is Dark Blue.

When the column filter is selected the dropdown values are in White and the background is also White.

I would like to set the Filter Values in the Dropdown to Black and leave the column name in White, but cannot find the name of the dropdown value to set it in my css.  I have set the .ms-viewheadertr A:link to black and it set both areas to black.

My company has disabled SharePoint designer.

I have been googling this like crazy and have had no luck.  Any insight is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The class seems to be:

ms-core-menu-link

I turned the filter list fire engine red with the dev tools using .ms-core-menu-link:link